# how to let one scene know an argument value of another?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In the `LevelsScene` class I have the code below for selecting a level. The `level` is simply a string value.

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if button1.containsPoint(location){
            let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size, level:"Level1")
            self.view?.presentScene(gameScene)
        } else if button2.containsPoint(location){
            let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size, level:"Level2")
            self.view?.presentScene(gameScene)
        } else if button3.containsPoint(location){
            let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size, level:"Level3")
            self.view?.presentScene(gameScene)
        }
    }
}
```

In the `GameOverScene` class I would like to pass the level string value to the following code:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let gameScene = GameScene(size: self.size, level:currentLevel) // where current level has been set to one of the levels
    self.view?.presentScene(gameScene)
}
```

The `GameScene` knows the `currentLevel` but how can I let `GameOverScene` know this value without creating an instance of the `gameScene`?

Comment: To simply answer your question. Let the GameOverScene have a property called currentLevel which you set before making the transition to the scene. (This sounds like an important part of the game-state however, so it might make sense to think about how you want to handle this in general).

Comment: thanks, it's working. Unfortunately my reputation score is not high enough to give you an upvote

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a global string variable on your view controller that represents your GameOverScene. What you will need to do is set the value of this variable when you segue to that screen.

1.) You will need to name the segue (by clicking on it in the storyboard) with an identifier, in this example, "GameOverSegue".

2.) Add a prepareforsegue: method that checks the segue identifier and then sets the level on the view controller for GameOver:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
//check to make sure it is the game over segue being called
if (segue.identifier == "GameOverSegue") {
//set the gameOverVC variable as an instance of the GameOverViewController
    if let gameOverVC: GameOverViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? GameOverViewController {
//set the variable on that vc to be the value of the currentLevel string
                gameOverVC.level = currentLevel
        }
    }
}
```

3.) Wherever you want to programmatically call a segue, you use this code:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GameOverSegue", sender: self)
```

Comment: Sprite Kit doesn't use segues to transition scenes.

Comment: Ah - didn't notice it was sprite kit specific... oops